Create list of dictionaries from Postgres table
I want to create a list of dictionaries from a postgres table. I use this code:
rows_dict = cur.fetchall() # fetch all rows from the Postgres Database
  
columns = []
entities_list = []
for column in cur.description:
    columns.append(column[0].lower())
entities = {}
for row in rows_dict:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        entities[columns[i]] = row[i]
        if isinstance(row[i], str):
            entities[columns[i]] = row[i].strip()
    print('Output-A:', entities)
    entities_list.append(entities) # add dictionary to the entity_list

print('Output-B:', entities_list) # Here I get a list with x-times the same dictionary... Why?

Output-A is what I expect at this indent level (and which is correct): multiple dictionaries. With an .append(entities) I want to add these dictionaries to the entity_list. However, the entity_list is populated multiple times with the same (=last!) dictionary in the loop. I do not understand what is going wrong as the .append(entities) is at the same indent as the Output-A. Any idea what is going wrong there?

If you're using psycopg then you can just use conn = psycopg.connect(DSN, row_factory=psycopg.rows.dict_row). Then psycopg does all the work for you. Or conn.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) if you want to have dict rows only for some queries.

@Dunes Assuming OP is using psycopg 3+ – I think the syntax and name is different for psycopg2?

In the end I found out that creating a copy of the dictionary and add it to the list ( entities_list.append(entities.copy()) solved the issue. I have no idea why...

For psycopg(3) read Row factory in particular psycopg.rows.dict_row() for psycopg2  see Connection/cursor subclasses in particular class psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor()

You're declaring entities outside the loop, so you end up updating the same object over and over again.
However, all of your code simplifies to a couple of list comprehensions:
def strip_if_string(val):
    if isinstance(val, str):
        return val.strip()
    return val


columns = [column[0].lower() for column in cur.description]
entities_list = [dict(zip(columns, (strip_if_string(v) for v in row))) for row in cur.fetchall()]


I solved the issue (see above). Will check you solution too. Thanks!
